# save method not writing to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :personas
  has_many :stories, through: :persona

  validates_presence_of :name

  attr_accessor :name, :default_persona_id
  after_create :create_first_persona

private
  def create_first_persona
    @persona = Persona.new
    @persona.user = self
    @persona.name = self.name
    if @persona.save
      make_first_persona_default
    end
  end

  def make_first_persona_default
    @user = self
    @user.default_persona_id = @user.personas.first.id
    @user.save!(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

What it does is create a Persona each time a User signs up and then sets that Persona's id as the User's default_persona_id.

Everything works except `make_first_persona_default`. When I check the user in rails console default_persona_id is nil.

I'm on Rails 4.

**UPDATE**

Edited make_first_persona_default to Taryn East's

```
def make_first_persona_default
    unless self.update_attribute(:default_persona_id, self.personas.first.id)
      raise "got an error trying to save persona: #{self.errors.inspect}"
    end
  end
```

default_persona_id is still nil

```
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 13, email: "[FILTERED]", encrypted_password: "[FILTERED]", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-10-01 02:09:19", last_sign_in_at: "2013-10-01 02:09:19", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-10-01 02:09:19", updated_at: "2013-10-01 02:09:19", default_persona_id: nil>
```

Here's my schema for User.

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "default_persona_id"
  end
```

and the migration which I used to add the default_persona_id column.

```
class AddActivePersonaToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :default_persona_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder what this line is doing in your `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :name, :default_persona_id
```

Did you mean `accessible`? Creating accessor this way will override `ActiveRecord` accessor, so assigning `default_persona_id` will only set instance variable `@default_persona_id` and will have no effect on database.

Comment: That was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

In reality - there's no reason why we have to lose the context.
Also - rather than creating one and then adding myself as a related user - you can create the persona directly on the association, and it will automatically link itself.

I'd do it this way:

```
private
  def create_first_persona
    persona = self.personas.build(:name => self.name)
    if persona.save!
      self.update_attribute(:default_persona_id, persona.id)
    end
  end
```

If you wish to continue with the two methods manner, the build will help with that.
I suspect the problem in your original code is that you are not building on the association - and thus the 
"personas" needs a reload before the user can find the new persona.

Also you don't need to fetch out the current user the way you do.. you already have self, so just use self. eg:

```
  def make_first_persona_default
    self.default_persona_id = self.personas.first.id
    self.save!(:validate => false)
  end
```

or even better, you're only setting one attribute... so use update attribute

```
  def make_first_persona_default
    self.update_attribute(:default_persona_id, self.personas.first.id)
  end
```

Comment: Not getting any errors for the first snippet as @persona is saving. I suppose you want to test self.update_attributes?

Comment: Updated my question to include more info. By the way is update_attributes going to bypass the name validation?

Comment: No. But by the time you get to this point, you have already run and finished the "create" so it should already be valid. If it's not valid - the code will fail well before getting to the after_create hook.

Comment: I've updated the example to call save with the persona id we've just generated. You don't really need these tow be two methods, and you don't need to go away and get the set of personas.

Comment: If you really want the second method separate - it's altogether possible that you need to "reload" to actually find the new set of personas.